# XML DOM parsing on URL issue

Tags: android, url, dom, xml-parsing, domparser

I'm implementing **XML DOM Parsing**, Whenever I access the XML from assets  it displays the values in **TextView** and works fine, but it neither retrieve values nor XML from the URL although the XML is the same in the URL.

My **Manifest.java** contains the *internet permissions*.

How do I retrieve the values ?

> **MainActivity.java**

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView tv1;
Button btn;
String url;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    try {
       //InputStream is = getAssets().open("employees.xml");

        String downloadURL="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/uploadstreamowl.appspot.com/o/xml%2Fxmluser.xml?alt=media&token=eba1b510-eb18-495c-930f-24ed27eb8fde";
        URL url1=new URL(downloadURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream inputStream=connection.getInputStream();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
       DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputStream);
        dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        // doc.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new URL(url).openStream());

        Element element=doc.getDocumentElement();
        element.normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("video");
        for (int i=0; i<nList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nList.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element2 = (Element) node;
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"\nvideoq : " + getValue("videoq", element2)+"\n");
                url=getValue("videoq", element2);
                Log.i(url,"This is the url key");
                //tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"Salary : " + getValue("salary", element2)+"\n");
                //tv1.setText(tv1.getText()+"-----------------------");
            }
        }//end of for loop

    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}


    Button btn = (android.widget.Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);



   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://streamowl.com/YouTubeTest/YouTube_IFrame.html?vid="+url));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
private static String getValue(String tag, Element element) {
    NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
    Node node = (Node) nodeList.item(0);
    return node.getNodeValue();
}

}
```

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how to step through your code with a debugger.  We are unlikely to guess the problem.

Comment: Thankyou! found the error! :)